# Android Async Task not reaching onPostExecute

Tags: android, asynchronous

I have an android app that is using an async task to validate login information.  The onpostexecute is never reached and I can't add @Override to it in order to make it run.  When I try to @Override it eclipse says that it must override a method of a supertype.  Here is the code.

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask <LoginObject, Void, Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(LoginObject... params)
    {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://softeng.cs.uwosh.edu/students/cs342g6/login.php");
        Boolean response = false;
        try
        {
            //Convert the login object to XML
            XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF-8"));
            xstream.alias("Login", LoginObject.class);
            String xml = xstream.toXML(login);

            // Pass the XML as a StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xml,HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            System.out.println("MADE IT TO RESPONSE");
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            String resp = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            System.out.println(resp);
            response = convertToBool(resp);
            if(response)
                System.out.println("true");
            else
                System.out.println("false");
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success)
{
    System.out.println("In onPostExecute");
    mAuthTask = null;
    showProgress(false);

    if (success)
    {
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        mPasswordView
                .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
        mPasswordView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is most likely related to two `onPostExecute()` methods. check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `onPostExecute()`s remove the empty one and make sure the one that does something is inside the AsyncTask class.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
{
    System.out.println("In onPostExecute");
    mAuthTask = null;
    showProgress(false);

    if (success)
    {
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        mPasswordView
                .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
        mPasswordView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I posted code with extra stuff added by auto-fix in eclipse.  It turned out that I had the onPostExecute outside of the class, but the above answers are correct for the code posted.